# Grab first occurrence of repeated fields - XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an xml file with the same information repeated and would like to use xslt to grab the first instance and ignore the rest. Here is what the XML file looks like:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Report_Data>
    <Report_Entry>
        <Cust_Name>Test 1</Cust_Name>
        <Cust_ID>Cust_ID_1</Cust_ID>
    </Report_Entry>
    <Report_Entry>
        <Cust_Name>Test 1</Cust_Name>
        <Cust_ID>Cust_ID_2</Cust_ID>
    </Report_Entry>
    <Report_Entry>
        <Cust_Name>Test 1</Cust_Name>
        <Cust_ID>Cust_ID_3</Cust_ID>
    </Report_Entry>
</Report_Data>
```

If you are wondering why there are duplicate entries, its because there are duplicate entries in the database and the xml file grabs all of those entries.

In my xslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"     
    xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
    exclude-result-prefixes="fn wd xs xsl">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
    <root>
        <output_id>
            <xsl:value-of select="/Report_Data/Report_Entry/Cust_ID"></xsl:value-of>
        </output_id>
    </root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <output_id>Cust_ID_1 Cust_ID_2 Cust_ID_3</output_id>
</root>
```

I would like to know if there is a function to grab to first element value it encounters like `<xsl:value-of select="/Report_Data/Report_Entry/Cust_ID[0]"></xsl:value-of>`

I can always use the substring before method using a space as a delimeter, but I would like to know if there is a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing this part:

```
<output_id>
    <xsl:value-of select="/Report_Data/Report_Entry/Cust_ID"></xsl:value-of>
</output_id>
```

to:

```
<output_id>
    <xsl:value-of select="/Report_Data/Report_Entry[1]/Cust_ID" />
</output_id>
```

For the protocol, we are assuming here that the report contains only one "real" entry.

Comment: It looks like I was close, just had the wrong index value and had it on the wrong node. Thanks